# Create business note at evernote

Tags: evernote

I want to create business note at evernote and i am using same function like:

```
`$accessToken='Evernote Token';
$client = new \Evernote\Client($accessToken, SANDBOX);
$advancedClient = $client->getAdvancedClient(); 
$notestore = $advancedClient->getNoteStore();
$notestore->createNote($note);`
```

We are getting error and we have also tried with

```
`$notestore->createNote($accessToken,$note);`
```

Comment: We can create personal note but business note giving error